# Mask Image as background on scroll on page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, background-image

I am following this [website](https://www.kodewithklossy.com/) to create scroll animation.
I am trying to show image behind some text after page scroll. But somehow zIndex of Image always up for the image. I just want element with zIndex 33 or greater than image should always be top. I dont know why it is not following element zIndex rather following parent zIndex only.

```
const fixedContainer = (
    <Grid
        item
        sx={{
            position: imageScrolled ? 'static' : 'fixed',
            top: '77px',
            minHeight: 'calc(100vh - 77px)',
            //top: `${landingRef?.current?.offsetTop}px`,
            //minHeight: `${landingRef?.current?.offsetHeight}px`,
                paddingTop: '97px',
                background: 'radial-gradient(105.49% 105.49% at 50% -5.49%, #29C05B 0%, #00852C 100%)',
                zIndex: 1
        }}
    >
        <Typography variant="h1" align="center" sx={{ color: '#fff', position: 'relative', zIndex: 33 }}>
            GIRLS CODE
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h1" align="center" sx={{ color: '#fff', position: 'relative', zIndex: 33 }}>
            RISING
        </Typography>
            
            <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: 1 }}>
                Nearly 98 Million of farmers children around the world are forced to work in the agriculture industry,
                according to recent reports. It is virtually impossible for farmers children to have access to education since
                they have to work with their families in the agricultural fields in order to help. To go to school is a dream
                for these children, not to mention the possibility of having a good future.
            </Typography>
            <Button variant="contained" sx={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
                Get in touch with us
            </Button>
        
    </Grid>
);
```

This is my parent container

```
    <Grid container direction="column" sx={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        {/* landing */}
        <Grid item sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Grid container direction="column" sx={{ minHeight: '100vh', position: 'relative' }}>
                <Header sx={{ background: '#0D973A' }} sticky />
                <Grid
                    item
                    ref={landingRef}
                    sx={{
                        flex: 1,
                        background: 'radial-gradient(105.49% 105.49% at 50% -5.49%, #29C05B 0%, #00852C 100%)'
                    }}
                ></Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {/* image */}
        <Grid item sx={{ width: '100%' }} ref={shutterImageRef}>
            <img                    src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/827c6d_fed491c3158c44219f1d6abe281143de~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1266,h_923,fp_0.52_0.48,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/JordynBriellePhoto_Seattle142.jpg"
                alt="Shutter Image"
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', zIndex: 2, position: 'relative' }}
            />
        </Grid>

        {fixedContainer}
        <Grid item sx={{ height: '5000px' }}></Grid>
    </Grid>
```